# Use max value of a column to restart postgresql sequence

Tags: postgresql, max, sequence, alter

I need to restart the table sequence after manually importing data and want to dynamically use the maximum value (+1) currently present in the id column.

I identify the value with

```
SELECT coalesce(MAX("id")+1) FROM "termine";
```

And I update the sequence with

```
ALTER SEQUENCE termine_id_seq RESTART WITH 123;
```

How can I use the MAX id within the ALTER instead of the "123"?

Answer (score 2):

Use the setval helper function.

```
select pg_catalog.setval('termine_id_seq'::regclass, MAX("id"),true) FROM "termine";
```